# Visual Studio error?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

About a half dozen times now, I’ve been doing a regular chore in Visual Studio – either running a unit test or simply compiling, updating something from SVN or whatever, and visual studio just disappears… it shuts down and goes away instantly… it is fine when I restart it, and I don’t see the problem again for a while… it keeps happening, and for random reasons… has anyone else experienced this?

One thought is that i'm using AnkhSVN, but if you've had this problem and don't experience this, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the devs on my team see this problem quite often. It isn't AnkhSVN because we don't use it. I believe it is C++ intellisense, but that is just a feeling. Sometimes it happens when we are not doing anything. We will go for coffee, come back and it is just gone.

It never happens to me on smaller projects, but happens frequently on our large (several million lines, dozens of projects) solution with a mix of unmanaged C++, managed C++ and C#.

We have seen it less frequently since upgrading to SP1.

Comment: this could be the case - i have pretty much only experienced this when i'm working on large solutions

Answer (score 2):

There's a good chance that it's one of your addins that are causing this.

If you are able to recreate when it is happening, try doing it with a variety of combination of addins (If you are only running AnkhSVN, then try only with and without that).

It's far from unlikely that Anhk can do this, so start by identifying this for certain.

Comment: The only addins we use are TestDriven.NET, SlickEdit Gadgets and Resharper if that helps narrow your list.

Comment: Actually, most of our developers don't use most of those. SlickEdit Gadgets is common though.

Comment: SlickEdit Gadgets is what caused my machine to die.

Comment: i've only got AnkhSVN as an addin, and i use NAnt sometimes, but just as an external tool - and this problem doesn't occur when i'm doing a NAnt build

Answer (score 1):

Definitely an addin.  I experienced a similar issue, but it would bluescreen my machine.  After uninstalling the plugin( it was SlickEdit Gadgets), I never experienced the issue again.  Try uninstalling plugins.  Or updating ankhSVN.